# Vector-valued function for 2 point charges

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I try plotting such vector field, but I'm not getting the function behind it.

My best guess for $E: \vec{r} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\y\end{array}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \quad E(x,y) = \underbrace{\dfrac{\mathrm{c}\cdot Q_1}{\vert\vec{r}\vert^3}\cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\y\end{array}\right)}_{Q_1^+}  + \underbrace{\dfrac{\mathrm{c}\cdot Q_2}{\vert\vec{r}\vert^3}\cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\y\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}2\\0\end{array}\right)}_{Q_2^+ \quad\text{displaced}} $

But the plot ain't right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field at a position $\mathbf x$ caused by a point charge $q$ at point $\mathbf x'$ is given by
$$
\mathbf E = \frac{q}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf r}
$$
(in Gaussian units), where $r=|\mathbf x-\mathbf x'|$ is the distance between the two points, and $\hat{\mathbf r} = (\mathbf x-\mathbf x')/r$ is the unit vector that points from $\mathbf x'$ to $\mathbf x$. If you then multiply the denominator and numerator by $r$ you can transform this into
$$
\mathbf E = \frac{q}{r^3}{\mathbf r},
$$
where $\mathbf r=\mathbf x-\mathbf x'$ is the separation vector between the two charges.

If you implement this correctly, then the plot will appear as required. On the other hand, if you input the wrong quantities, then that won't work.

Particular points to pay attention to are checking that the distances $r$ between the point and the charge are correct, that you're using the correct separation vectors, and that you are distributing correctly when you multiply $(\mathbf x-\mathbf x')$ by a scalar.